# distributing r distinct objects into n-distinct boxes when repetition is allowed

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are 5 students and we are trying to create 3 distinct commissions which every student must be in at least one commission and every commission must have at least 2 members. what is the number of distributions?

I found 2 solutions but they both seems to be incorrect

**Solution 1**

Every student must be in at least 1 commission so for each student there are the following ways to join to commissions (he/she must be in one or two or three commissions, since the order doesn't matter the $C(n,r)$ seems to be legal)

$C(1,3)+C(2,3)+C(3,3) = 7$

There are 5 students so $7 * 5 = 35$ ways are possible. this solution is not right because it doesn't guarantee the non emptiness of commissions.

**Solution 2**

Every commission must have at least 2 members so for every commission we can distribute students in the following ways:

$C(2,5)+C(3,5)+C(4,5)+C(5,5) = 26$

there are three commissions so there are $26 * 3 = 78$ ways of distribution.

this solution is not right because it doesn't guarantee that every student is joint in any of the commissions.

**So what is the solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we have to use the inclusion-exclusion principle. Let's count the arrangements that satisfy that each class has at least two students.

For each class there are $2^5-5-1$ subsets with at least $2$ elements. Thus there are $(2^5-6)^3=26^3$ possibilities. We now use the inclusion exclusion principle. How many of these possibilities leave child $A$ without a class? $(2^4-5)^3=11^3$. How many leave childs $A$ and $B$ without classes?$(2^3-4)^3=4^3$.How many leave childs $ABC$ without classes? $(2^2-3)=1$

We now use the inclusion-exclusion principle to see there are $26^3-\binom{5}{1}(11^3)+\binom{5}{2}(4^3)-\binom{5}{3}(1)=11551$ ways to do it.